# Are there any algorithm for schedule match

Tags: algorithms

I am making a game. This game divide players into groups. Each group has N players in even number and will schedule player in the same group to fight each other in pair everyday

I need to have every player meet another only once. And each day everyone will have one fight

Currently now I have 14 players in group. So I making table of 7 matches in 13 days by my hand. It then only work for 14 players, change the amount and I need to redo this schedule table

So are there any algorithm better than this?

Comment: If you just want everybody in the group to fight everybody else once, for $N$ players you can do it in $N-1$ days for $N$ even, in $N$ days for $N$ odd.  See my answer http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55439/gay-speed-dating-problem/55442#55442  Where does $26$ days come from?  If pairs means you fight two on two and want every pair to fight every other pair, you should make that clear.

Comment: @RossMillikan Right it actually 13 days. I forgot that in my game I have twice for same pair, for A vs B and B vs A so it is 13*2 in my game. But anyway it use the same algorithm

Comment: You can look up the [Howell movement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplicate_bridge_movements#Howell_Movements) used by bridge players.  That meets your needs.  It is what was in my answer as well.